# pandas count occurrences during time window on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with this pattern of events

```
df = {
    '2017-11-28 11:00': 'event1',
    '2017-11-28 11:01': 'event1',
    '2017-11-28 11:02': 'event1', <-----
    '2017-11-28 11:03': 'event2',
    '2017-11-28 11:04': 'event2',
    '2017-11-28 11:05': 'event1',
    '2017-11-28 11:06': 'event1',
    '2017-11-28 11:07': 'event1', <-----
    '2017-11-28 11:08': 'event2',
    '2017-11-28 11:09': 'event2',
    '2017-11-28 11:10': 'event2',
    }
```

What I want to do is, for every `event1` followed by one or many `event2`s, count the number of these `event2`s occurring during a specified time window, say 3 mins after that `event1`.
The arrows indicate the beginning of the time window.
Any help please?

Comment: Is it a DataFrame or a Series?

Comment: That does not look like a dataframe to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a series there. In which case you can do:

```
threshold = (s.index.to_series()
  .groupby((s.eq('event1') & s.shift(-1).eq('event2')).cumsum())
  .transform('min') + pd.to_timedelta('3Min')    # adjust threshold here
)

(s.eq('event2') & (s.index < threshold)).sum()
# out 4
```